# Creating lots of moving UIImageviews slows down app

Tags: performance, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I have an app which has `UIImageView`s spawn at the top of the screen every 0.3 seconds and move down the screen. This makes the app be very slow and relatively unresponsive. Should I use sprites instead of image views? Or is there a way to make my  image views more efficient?

Comment: are you having the ImageView's move in a thread? or in the main thread? if it's in the main thread that will slow down the app

Comment: What is the main thread?

Comment: Don't create new views everytime you want to spawn a new view. Try to reuse existing views, like UITableView does.

Comment: But isnt that the same as just releasing the view once it hits the bottom of the screen and then making a new one?